# AWS data transfer pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am interested in setting up an AWS host that needs to occasionally pull data from another Internet site.

According to the AWS pricing calculator, inbound Internet data transfers are free but outbound data transfers are not. Does this mean I am only charged for the size of the HTTP request but the HTTP response is free? I searched but cannot find an answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. You may be able to get help from [sf]. Also, short answer: Yes, the HTTP response is free as it counts as incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In your scenario, only requests incur charges. Also note that the first 100GB is free. From [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/):

> AWS customers receive 100GB of data transfer out to the internet free each month, aggregated across all
> AWS Services and Regions (except China and GovCloud). The 100 GB free tier for data transfer out to the internet
> is global and does not apply separately or individually to AWS Regions.